# How to use performSelector:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How to use performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:? here in onthread i have to use other thread not main thread. How to create other thread? give me some sample code.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you have a thread pool to manage, it's easier to use `-performSelectorInBackground:…`:

```
[object performSelectorInBackground:@selector(method:) withObject:foo];
```

---

If you're going to create a thread, use

```
NSThread* thread = [[NSThread alloc] init];
[object performSelector:@selector(method:)
               onThread:thread
             withObject:foo
          waitUntilDone:YES];
[thread release];
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. but this is not working. method not calling.

Comment: Hi Kenny, you need to run a run-loop in the target thread so that the `performSelector:` input source is dealt with. So I don't think your code to work...

Comment: TM: your answer works perfectly. Thanks. I don't know why the poster couldn't get it to work and never accepted your answer, but it is correct. Thanks.